# How to Convert the nested array to xml in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, nested

How can I convert the following nested array into xml file?  What will the XML file look like?

```
Array(
array('name'=>'Jone Smith','phone'=>'416-689-9865'),
array('name'=>'Jane    Ling','phone'=>'658-985-5222')
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$your_array= array ('key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2', 'second_array' => array ('key3' => 'val3','key4' => 'val4'),);
$toXml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($your_array, array ($toXml, 'addChild'));
print_r($toXml->asXML());
```

Other alternate is to use `array_walk`.
The array_walk_recursive() function runs each array element in a user-made function. The array's keys and values are parameters in the function. The difference between this function and the array_walk() function is that with this function you can work with deeper arrays (an array inside an array)

Comment: This is a rather clever solution, but it breaks when a value is empty. Not sure why though.